# Bash rename string that starts with digits

Tags: bash, sed, rename

I have folders with multiple files with names like `2024_CULT_IMAGE_2012_03.shp` and `CULT_IMAGE_2017_03.shp` How can I test if the string begins with  digits. I know how to rename them when I have tested them. I have used reg-ex to test if a file contains digits but I am unsure how to test beginning of the string.

```
if [[  $file =~ [0-9]   ]];
then
    do something
```

The output I expect is `CULT_IMAGE.shp`.

Comment: same filename for all files?

Comment: That sounds like a homework assignment. So I won't give you the answer, just the tools to do it yourself. You want to match the _beginning_ of the filename so you need `^` in your regexp. Then you want one or more digits, so look up how to specify "one or more" of something. Then you can use the something like `newfilname=$(echo $file | sed 's/<pattern>/<pattern>/')` to make a new name. Things to think about: can the filename have spaces in it? Do you want the newfile name to start with an underscore and if not, how can you fix it, but not remove the underscore if there were no leading digits?

Comment: thanks .It is not a homework. I know all about renaming all occurrences of digits using sed,awk. All I asked for was how to check the beginning of my string

Comment: try if [[ "$file" =~ "^[0-9]" ]];then

Comment: this does not work. It doesn't test if a string begins with digits

Comment: Check the example in my answer, it DO check for string which starts with numbers

Comment: ` for file in *;do echo $file; if [[  "$file" =~ "^[0-9]"    ]];  then echo "manage" ; else echo "nothing to do"; fi done
2024_CULT_IMAGE_2012_03.shp
nothing to do
CULT_IMAGE_2017_1111132.shp
nothing to do`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `rename` utility

```
rename 's/^\d+_//' *.shp
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove EVERY digits with `sed` you can just do `sed 's/[0-9]//g'`

So you should be able to adapt it quickly to remove only the first digits

Answer (score 0):

## Before

```
ls -lrt
total 4
-rw-rw-r--  1 user super 173 May 20 09:58 main
-rw-rw-r--  1 user super   0 May 20 10:13 CULT_IMAGE_2017_1111132.shp
-rw-rw-r--  1 user super   0 May 20 10:13 2024_CULT_IMAGE_2012_03.shp


#Execution:Rename files which starts with numbers.

./main
```

## After Execution

```
ls -lrt
total 4
-rw-rw-r--  1 user super 173 May 20 09:58 main
-rw-rw-r--  1 user super   0 May 20 10:13 CULT_IMAGE_2017_1111132.shp
-rw-rw-r--  1 user super   0 May 20 10:13 CULT_IMAGE.shp
```

## File

```
cat main
for file in *.shp
    do

if [[ "$file" =~ "^[0-9]" ]];then


newName=$(echo $file | sed -e 's/[0-9]//g' -e 's/^_//' -e 's/__.shp/.shp/')

mv $file $newName
fi
     done
```